# Нажатие ToggleButton

Tags: java, javafx

Я храню ObservableList, в каждом из которых присутствует ToggleButton, который управляет соответствующим ему потоком через

```
on.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (on.isSelected()) {
                on.setGraphic(viewOn);
                thread.resume();
            }
            else {
                on.setGraphic(viewOff);
                thread.suspend();
            }
            checkActivity();
});
```

Я хочу добавить возможность разом переключать ToggleButton на всех элементах ObservableList, т.е. добавить глобальный ToggleButton вроде "All on/off".
Проблема заключается в том, при реальном нажатии мыши пользователем значение isSelected меняется, а когда делаешь

```
for (AnchorPane bot: listOfBots) {
     bot.getChildren().get(1).fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
}
```

, то переключения не происходит и выполняется только прописанное в setOnAction(). Соответственно значение значения isSelected - неверные и ничего не происходит. Как можно решить это?
Для лучшего понимания ситуации добавил скриншот.
[image: Для наглядности]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вам нужно отслеживать именно нажатие на ToggleButton или всё-таки отслеживать изменение положения статуса selected?

Если второе, то слушатель нужно вешать на **событие изменения статуса selected**

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
toggleButton.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        System.out.println("Do this");
    }
});
toggleButton.setSelected(true);
```

В результате выполнения кода, toggleButton будет и отображаться как выбранный, а так же произойдёт выполнение кода события.

Т.е. вам нужно поменять тип события с onAction на изменение статуса selected (`selectedProperty().addListener`) и не отправлять ложное событие (`bot.getChildren().get(1).fireEvent(new ActionEvent());` ), а просто изменять selected (`bot.getChildren().get(1).setSelected(true)`)

Comment: Именно bot.getChildren().get(1).setSelected(true) я не могу использовать (Cannot resolve method 'setSelected' in 'Node'). И здесь отслеживаю нажатие, т.к. не смог получить доступ к статусу isSelected(). Я ведь не могу влиять на isSelected() для Node.

Comment: Если вам нужно включить все ToggleButton из AnchorPane, вы ведь можете написать что-то вроде: https://pastebin.com/xne72Egb

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало. Не додумался, что isSelected() будет передан по ссылке.